# Python on Windows - how to wait for multiple child processes?

Tags: python, windows, asynchronous

How to wait for multiple child processes in Python on Windows, without active wait (polling)? Something like this *almost* works for me:

```
proc1 = subprocess.Popen(['python','mytest.py'])
proc2 = subprocess.Popen(['python','mytest.py'])    
proc1.wait()
print "1 finished"
proc2.wait()
print "2 finished"
```

The problem is that when `proc2` finishes before `proc1`, the parent process will still wait for `proc1`. On Unix one would use `waitpid(0)` in a loop to get the child processes' return codes as they finish - how to achieve something like this in Python on Windows?

Comment: can you describe the waitpid(0) you'd use on unix?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.waitpid 
`waitpid(0)` on unix waits (unless `WNOHANG` is in the option) for any available child status and returns `(processid,status)` tuple.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It might seem overkill, but, here it goes:

```
import Queue, thread, subprocess

results= Queue.Queue()
def process_waiter(popen, description, que):
    try: popen.wait()
    finally: que.put( (description, popen.returncode) )
process_count= 0

proc1= subprocess.Popen( ['python', 'mytest.py'] )
thread.start_new_thread(process_waiter,
    (proc1, "1 finished", results))
process_count+= 1

proc2= subprocess.Popen( ['python', 'mytest.py'] )
thread.start_new_thread(process_waiter,
    (proc2, "2 finished", results))
process_count+= 1

# etc

while process_count > 0:
    description, rc= results.get()
    print "job", description, "ended with rc =", rc
    process_count-= 1
```

Comment: Well, if the call doesn't support parallelism then one has to implement it outside :-) Thanks!

Comment: In case you're using Python 3, the `Queue` module was renamed to `queue`, and the `thread` module to `_thread`.

Comment: It's not Christmas yet, but my wish is for Python to add a new waitForMultiple function that shields the user from all this low-level stuff and make it work the same regardless of whether we're on Linux or Windows. :)

Answer (score 7):

Building on zseil's answer, you can do this with a mix of subprocess and win32 API calls. I used straight ctypes, because my Python doesn't happen to have win32api installed. I'm just spawning sleep.exe from MSYS here as an example, but clearly you could spawn any process you like. I use OpenProcess() to get a HANDLE from the process' PID, and then WaitForMultipleObjects to wait for any process to finish.

```
import ctypes, subprocess
from random import randint
SYNCHRONIZE=0x00100000
INFINITE = -1
numprocs = 5
handles = {}

for i in xrange(numprocs):
    sleeptime = randint(5,10)
    p = subprocess.Popen([r"c:\msys\1.0\bin\sleep.exe", str(sleeptime)], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
    h = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE, False, p.pid)
    handles[h] = p.pid
    print "Spawned Process %d" % p.pid

while len(handles) > 0:
    print "Waiting for %d children..." % len(handles)
    arrtype = ctypes.c_long * len(handles)
    handle_array = arrtype(*handles.keys())
    ret = ctypes.windll.kernel32.WaitForMultipleObjects(len(handle_array), handle_array, False, INFINITE)
    h = handle_array[ret]
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(h)
    print "Process %d done" % handles[h]
    del handles[h]
print "All done!"
```

Answer (score 5):

Twisted has an [asynchronous process-spawning API](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.1.0/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorProcess.html) which works on Windows.  There are actually several different implementations, many of which are not so great, but you can switch between them without changing your code.

Answer (score 4):

Twisted on Windows will perform an active wait under the covers. If you don't want to use threads, you will have to use the win32 API to avoid polling. Something like this:

```
import win32process
import win32event

# Note: CreateProcess() args are somewhat cryptic, look them up on MSDN
proc1, thread1, pid1, tid1 = win32process.CreateProcess(...)
proc2, thread2, pid2, tid2 = win32process.CreateProcess(...)
thread1.close()
thread2.close()

processes = {proc1: "proc1", proc2: "proc2"}

while processes:
    handles = processes.keys()
    # Note: WaitForMultipleObjects() supports at most 64 processes at a time
    index = win32event.WaitForMultipleObjects(handles, False, win32event.INFINITE)
    finished = handles[index]
    exitcode = win32process.GetExitCodeProcess(finished)
    procname = processes.pop(finished)
    finished.close()
    print "Subprocess %s finished with exit code %d" % (procname, exitcode)
```

Comment: You are wrong about the threaded solution performing an active wait. I don't know about Twisted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [psutil](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> import psutil
>>> 
>>> proc1 = subprocess.Popen(['python','mytest.py'])
>>> proc2 = subprocess.Popen(['python','mytest.py'])    
>>> ls = [psutil.Process(proc1.pid), psutil.Process(proc2.pid)]
>>>
>>> gone, alive = psutil.wait_procs(ls, timeout=3)
```

'gone' and 'alive' are lists indicating which processes are gone and which ones are still alive.

Optionally you can specify a callback which gets invoked every time one of the watched processes terminates:

```
>>> def on_terminate(proc):
...     print "%s terminated" % proc
...
>>> gone, alive = psutil.wait_procs(ls, timeout=3, callback=on_terminate)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [psutil](https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
import psutil

with psutil.Popen(["python", "mytest.py"]) as proc1, psutil.Popen(
    ["python", "mytest.py"]
) as proc2:
    gone, alive = psutil.wait_procs([proc1, proc2], timeout=3)
```

'gone' and 'alive' are lists indicating which processes are gone and which ones are still alive.

Optionally you can specify a callback which gets invoked every time one of the watched processes terminates:

```
def on_terminate(proc):
    print "%s terminated" % proc

gone, alive = psutil.wait_procs(ls, timeout=3, callback=on_terminate)
```