# Python/Windows/ctypes: How to get process return status after calling WaitForMultipleObjects?

Tags: python, windows, process-management

I have the same use case as [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/100624/77070), and I really like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/573196/77070) except that I have one extra requirement: I need to get the return status from the child process.

Here's my attempt at modifying his program.  I'm a tourist in Windows-land and Python ctypes, so hopefully I haven't done anything dumb...

```
import ctypes, subprocess
from random import randint
import os
SYNCHRONIZE=0x00100000
PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION=0x0400
INFINITE = -1
numprocs = 5
handles = {}

class Err(BaseException): pass

for i in xrange(numprocs):
    sleeptime = randint(5,10)
    p = subprocess.Popen([r"c:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\sleep.exe", str(sleeptime)], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
    h = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, p.pid)
    handles[h] = p.pid
    print "Spawned Process %d" % p.pid

while len(handles) > 0:
    print "Waiting for %d children..." % len(handles)
    arrtype = ctypes.c_long * len(handles)
    handle_array = arrtype(*handles.keys())
    ret = ctypes.windll.kernel32.WaitForMultipleObjects(len(handle_array), handle_array, False, INFINITE)
    h = handle_array[ret]
    print "Process %d done" % handles[h]
    i = ctypes.c_int(0)
    pi = ctypes.pointer(i)
    if ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetExitCodeProcess(h, pi) == 0:
    err = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError()
        raise Err("GetExitCodeProcess: %d" % (err))
    print "Status code is: %d" % (i)
    if ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(h) == 0:
    err = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError()
    raise Err("CloseHandle: %d" % (err))
    del handles[h]
print "All done!
```

But when I run this, I get a failure:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 30, in <module>
    raise Err("GetExitCodeProcess: %d" % (err))
__main__.Err: GetExitCodeProcess: 6
```

It appears that [error 6 is ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  But I'm not sure why the handle is invalid; I asked for the `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` permission and the `CloseHandle()` call works fine if I comment out the `GetExitCodeProcess()` call.

Any ideas?  How can I get the status code after waiting for a bunch of processes?

Answer (score 1):

Using this exact Python code (the same as yours only some indents fixed and path to sleep.exe removed):

```
import ctypes, subprocess
from random import randint
import os
SYNCHRONIZE=0x00100000
PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION=0x0400
INFINITE = -1
numprocs = 5
handles = {}

class Err(BaseException): pass

for i in xrange(numprocs):
    sleeptime = randint(5,10)
    p = subprocess.Popen([r"sleep.exe", str(sleeptime)], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
    h = ctypes.windll.kernel32.OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, p.pid)
    handles[h] = p.pid
    print "Spawned Process %d" % p.pid

while len(handles) > 0:
    print "Waiting for %d children..." % len(handles)
    arrtype = ctypes.c_long * len(handles)
    handle_array = arrtype(*handles.keys())
    ret = ctypes.windll.kernel32.WaitForMultipleObjects(len(handle_array), handle_array, False, INFINITE)
    h = handle_array[ret]
    print "Process %d done" % handles[h]
    i = ctypes.c_int(0)
    pi = ctypes.pointer(i)
    if ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetExitCodeProcess(h, pi) == 0:
        err = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError()
        raise Err("GetExitCodeProcess: %d" % (err))
    print "Status code is: %d" % i.value
    if ctypes.windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(h) == 0:
        err = ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError()
        raise Err("CloseHandle: %d" % (err))
    del handles[h]

print "All done!"
```

gives me this output:

```
C:\tmp\pyt>python -V
Python 2.7.3

C:\tmp\pyt>python a.py
Spawned Process 4368
Spawned Process 268
Spawned Process 5792
Spawned Process 4744
Spawned Process 4484
Waiting for 5 children...
Process 5792 done
Status code is: 0
Waiting for 4 children...
Process 4484 done
Status code is: 0
Waiting for 3 children...
Process 268 done
Status code is: 0
Waiting for 2 children...
Process 4368 done
Status code is: 0
Waiting for 1 children...
Process 4744 done
Status code is: 0
All done!
```

So it seems to be working. Isn't your problem somewhere completely else? What OS are you using (mine is Vista)? Do you have the latest version of Python (2.7.3)? Isn't your "sleep.exe" broken somehow? Did you try another command?