# wait process until all subprocess finish?

Tags: python, subprocess, ipc

I have a main process which creates two or more sub processes, I want  main process to wait until all sub processes finish their operations and exits?

```
 # main_script.py

 p1 = subprocess.Popen(['python script1.py']) 
 p2 = subprocess.Popen(['python script2.py'])
 ... 
 #wait main process until both p1, p2 finish
 ...
```

Comment: use the wait method: `p1.wait(); p2.wait()`

Comment: check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6341358/subprocess-wait-not-waiting-for-popen-process-to-finish-when-using-threads

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100624/python-on-windows-how-to-wait-for-multiple-child-processes

Comment: BTW, `Popen(['python script1.py'])` won't work. Either do `Popen(['python', 'script1.py'])` (to be preferred) or `Popen('python script1.py', shell=True)`.

Comment: Not a duplicate--linked duplicate is specifically regarding Windows.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

A `Popen` object has a [`.wait()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) method exactly defined for this: to wait for the completion of a given subprocess (and, besides, for retuning its exit status).

If you use this method, you'll prevent that the process zombies are lying around for too long.

(Alternatively, you can use [`subprocess.call()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) or [`subprocess.check_call()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) for calling and waiting. If you don't need IO with the process, that might be enough. But probably this is not an option, because your if the two subprocesses seem to be supposed to run in parallel, which they won't with (`call()`/`check_call()`.)

If you have several subprocesses to wait for, you can do

```
exit_codes = [p.wait() for p in p1, p2]
```

(or maybe `exit_codes = [p.wait() for p in (p1, p2)]` for syntactical reasons)

which returns as soon as all subprocesses have finished. You then have a list of return codes which you maybe can evaluate.

Comment: If I have a list of processes that I need to wait for, but I want the wait to be interrupted the moment any of the processes has finished (so I can later resume it to wait for the remaining processes), how would I go about that?

Comment: @antred Then you should call `.wait()` with a (rather small)  timeout and process the results. AFAIR, it returns `None` if the said process wasn't terminated yet and a number if it was.

Comment: @glglgl Yeah, that would work, though I wanted to avoid having to actively poll, but I guess there may not be a way around it (I'm on a Windows machine). Also, apparently the same thing was asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100624/python-on-windows-how-to-wait-for-multiple-child-processes

Comment: @antred Of course - you can have a thread wait on each process and tell as soon as it finished. That would be a solution I didn't think of. It would lead to maximum responsiveness.

Comment: @glglgl I wish Python on Windows would just emulate what os.waitpid( 0 ) does on Unix. Even if, under the covers, the emulation would have to do the same thing the threaded solutions in that other SO post do, it would still be nice to have Python offer this functionality out-of-the-box.

Comment: @glglgl Thanks soo much for explaining the difference between `subprocess.call` and `subprocess.Popen` . It is really helpful to know that only the latter shows IO and runs in parallel!

Comment: tried with Python 3.8.8, this method does not work anymore.

Comment: @Franva I didn't know "does not work" is a valid way of describing an error. But maybe the edit I made to my answer solves your problem.

Answer (score 42):

```
subprocess.call
```

Automatically waits , you can also use:

```
p1.wait()
```