# Need a python count down clock that doesn't error when its done

Tags: python, timer, count, countdown, discord.py

```
def countdown(t):
    while t > 0:
        print(t)
        t = t-1
        time.sleep(1.0)
        if t == 0:
            print('blast off')
```

`T=20`

So this timer works well. It does what it needs, it counts which is what I want. But when it ends it stops my program I'm running it with and does a Timeouterror. Is there a countdown that won't do this or something I can add to it?

Comment: Is this specific to discord? I just tried the code you provided and it worked fine.

Comment: This code doesn't "error" when the countdown is done -- it *stops* because, well, you don't have any code after the loop. What do you expect to happen? The error is probably being triggered by code that you haven't shown.

Comment: How do you call this piece of code exactly ?

Comment: Assuming this code does raise a TimeoutError (which I'm not convinced of), can't you just do `try: ... except TimeoutError: ...` to prevent it from terminating your program entirely?

Comment: Is this a part of a bigger program?

Comment: @everyone yeah it is, but i just realized i have to call a background task because while it counts i can't call any other function. It's part of a bigger program so I'm thinking that's why its calling a timeout error. Sorry for the trouble, I'll see if i can figure it out now knowing theren's nothing wrong with this code specifically. Thanks.

Comment: @Philzeey Maybe this helps?
You could call another script for instance. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107714/wait-process-until-all-subprocess-finish

Comment: @AntonvBR hmmmm maybe. I'll give it some more look. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned both that this was a background task, and that this causes a `TimeoutError`. That's because D.py runs asyncio, and `time.sleep` is blocking, meaning that it stops all threads running while it processes. What you want is the async-friendly version, `await asyncio.sleep(1.0)` instead of `time.sleep(1.0)`.