# How to make sure the rest of the code doesn't run until the subprocess is done?

Tags: python, subprocess

I want to be able to pause my code, open the word document and edit it, and after saving the edits and exiting the document I want to keep running the rest of the code.
If I run it manually cell by cell it works, but when I run all cells at once the following cells are being run as soon as the word is open. I am not sure how to make sure the rest of the code doesn't start until I save and close the file.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["start", my_file],shell=True)
```

Comment: That's the purpose of the `start` command on Windows, isn't it? If you want to run Word, just run Word as a subprocess directly instead. `subprocess.call()` definitely waits for the subprocess to complete. (Once you get rid of the `start`, you can get rid of the `shell=True` too.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [wait process until all subprocess finish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15107714/wait-process-until-all-subprocess-finish)